# Orchard: Difference between Display.User() and New.User()

Tags: orchardcms

What is the difference between Display.User() and New.User() in Orchard templates?

I see this line of razor code in *Core\Shapes\Views\Layout.cshtml*:

```
    Model.Header.Add(Display.User(), "10");
```

Where as there is this line of code in *Themes\TheThemeMachine\Views\Layout.cshtml*:

```
    WorkContext.Layout.Footer.Add(New.User(), "10");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is a mistake and should be replaced by `Model.Header.Add(New.User(), "10");`.

`New.ShapeName()` instantiates a new shape but does not render it.

`@Display.ShapeName()` instantiates and renders a new shape.